# What is the best way to remove excessive duplicates from an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, duplicates

Consider the following object in Javascript (this is a very large object, so I have only included a portion of it).

[image]

**I want to apply the following:**

For each unique user, allow a maximum of 4 random leads and then remove the rest.

For example, if I have 10 different users, with each user appearing 5 times each, there will be 50 records in the object. I want to keep only 4 for each user (it does not matter which 4). This would leave a total of 40 records.

I am not really sure where to start with this problem, but this is what I have done so far:

1) Create an array containing a distinct list of users:

```
["1116", "1075", "1124"]
```

2) I am not sure what to do next. My guess is I need to loop through my object (lets call it leads) and then compare it to the unique users array. If there is a match, then a counter should be increased, but if the counter = 4 then the lead should be skipped. This is my pseudo code:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < leads.length; i++) {
      if (leads[i].user == //anything in the users array//) {
        //check for existing count property on the unique users array
        // if not exist, add a count property to the users array
        // else, if the count is 4, destroy [leads[i]]
      }//end if
    }//end for
```

Am I on the right track? Or does JavaScript have a better way of doing this?

Comment: Yes you are on the right track. Good luck.

Comment: make a look up table or Map object in which `user` value is the key and store `lead_id`'s as a value array. Look up for the `user` and If array length < 4 keep pushing in the `lead_id`

Comment: You may change the structure as  well, something like { useId: 1234, lead_ids: [a,b,c,d] } or even better users = { 123 : [a, b, c, d], 456 : [x,y,z] }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce`. Create an object and push lead, once its length is equal to 4 stop pushing it.

```js
var leads = [{lead_id: 2433867, user : '1116'}, {lead_id: 2433868, user : '1116'}, {lead_id: 2433869, user : '1116'}, {lead_id: 2433870, user : '1116'}, {lead_id: 2433871, user : '1116'}, {lead_id: 2433872, user : '1116'}, {lead_id: 2433873, user : '1116'}, {lead_id: 2433874, user : '1116'}];

var result = leads.reduce((res, lead) => {
  res[lead.user] = res[lead.user] || [];
  if(res[lead.user].length < 4)
    res[lead.user].push(lead); 
  return res;
},{})

console.log(Object.values(result)[0]);
```